Функция проверки условия, запуска другой функции и продолжение проверки условия!
Всем привет! Есть непростая для меня задача, имеется такая таблица с данными: 
Суть в чем: функция setF() проверяет столбец "В" на наличие TRUE, если находит TRUE, то она должна записать в переменную i значение из этой же строки но столбца "А", далее запустить другую функцию setM(i) с аргументом извлеченной переменной, затем продолжить выполнение функции setF(). И так пока не проверит все значения в столбце "В".
Каким образом это реализовать, в какую сторону копать? Не очень опытен в js, огромное спасибо всем за помощь!

Разобрался и даже заработало с первого раза, сам в шоке! Может кому то пригодится:
function myControl() {
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); // Доступ к таблице
  let sheets2 = ss.getSheetByName("h2"); // Доступ к листу 2
  let last2 = sheets2.getLastRow(); // Доступ к последней строке лист2
  let data = sheets2.getRange("G:G").getValues(); // Значения true\false
  let dataid = sheets2.getRange("B:B").getValues(); // id
  finder();

  function finder(i){
  let rowid = null;

  for (let i = 0; i < last2; i++) {
    if (data[i] == 'true') { // Проверяем значение на равенство 'true'
      rowid = dataid[i]; // Записываем значение id
      console.log('id :' + rowid + '\ в строке:' + [i+1])// Вывод в консоль
      let text3d = "Сообщение пользователю!"
      sendText(rowid,text3d); // Запуск функции отправки сообщений
      Utilities.sleep(5000);
    } 
  }  
    //Отправка сообщений ботом
  function sendText(tlgrm_id, text) {
    UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.telegram.org/bot<bot_t>/sendMessage?chat_id=' + tlgrm_id + '&text=' + encodeURIComponent(text));
    }
  }
}

